# React component won't align with react-bootstrap navbar

Tags: css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, react-bootstrap, google-maps-react

I'm trying to align and size a react component under a `Navbar` using `react-bootstrap v0.33.1`. I want the map to have the full width of the `Navbar` component and be centrally aligned beneath it. However, no matter how I place the component, it will do one of the following:

1. If I use the `<Grid>` and `<Col>` component to wrap the `<Map>` component, then the map is too far to the right.

```js
export default function Map() {
  return (
    <Grid>
      <Col md={12}>
        <MapContainer />
      </Col>
    </Grid>
  );
}
```

[image]

2. If I remove `<Grid> and` `then I end up with the`` component being the full width of my device screen.

```js
export default function Map() {
  return (
    <MapContainer />
  );
}
```

[image]

Here are the other components:

```js
function MapContainer(props) {
    const mapStyles = {
        width: '100%',
        height:'500px'
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <Map
                google={props.google}
                zoom={10}
                // style={{
                //     width: "300px"
                // }}
                style={mapStyles}
                initialCenter={{
                    lat: 47.6128856,
                    lng: -122.3631801
                }}
            />
        </div>
    )
}
```

```js
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App container">
      <Navbar fluid collapseOnSelect>
        <Navbar.Header>
          <Navbar.Brand>
            <Link to="/">Skatespots</Link>
          </Navbar.Brand>
          <Navbar.Toggle />
        </Navbar.Header>
          <Navbar.Collapse>
            <Nav pullRight>
              { isAuthenticated
                ? <NavItem onClick={handleLogout}>Logout</NavItem>
                : <>
                    <LinkContainer to="/signup">
                      <NavItem>Signup</NavItem>
                    </LinkContainer>
                    <LinkContainer to="/login">
                      <NavItem>Login</NavItem>
                    </LinkContainer>
                  </>
              }
            </Nav>
          </Navbar.Collapse>
      </Navbar>
      <AppContext.Provider value={{isAuthenticated, userHasAuthenticated}}>
        <Routes />
      </AppContext.Provider>
    </div>
  );
```

```css
.App {
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.App .navbar-brand {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

I do not know what the issue is and this simple issue is being such a pain. using a negative margin value seems like it'd be the wrong way to fix scenario 1 and using a fixed width with `px` seems like it wouldn't be dynamic for different screen sizes for scenario 2. Thanks.

Comment: there is some margins on the map component  causing this, try inspecting the map container.

Comment: @adel can I ask where you're finding the margin or what's leading you to believe that's the issue?

Comment: yes maybe the  google Map component is rendering a div that have a margin or extra width, plus if you post a codesandbox showcasing your issue would be better for help.

Comment: @adel sorry, not able to get codesandbox to show the navbar. We can see that `Map` doesn't have any margins added by default from the [source code](https://github.com/fullstackreact/google-maps-react/blob/master/src/index.js#L310-L323)